# Internal representation of string

Tags: common-lisp

In my understanding, everything in lisp is either an atom or a pair.

Is a string considered as an atom?

How does a lisp compiler know if string is a mere sequence of characters or a string?

What is the difference between `foo`, `'foo` and `"foo"` in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### String is an Atom

Your first statement is trivial in the sense that "atom" is defined as "not pair".

Thus a string is most definitely an atom:

```
(atom "a")
==> T
```

The class [`string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_string.htm)
is actually *defined* as a [`vector`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_vector.htm)
of [`character`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_ch.htm)s
(or its subtypes):

> A string is a specialized vector whose elements are of type character
>     or a subtype of type character. When used as a type specifier for
>     object creation, string means (vector character).

### What? Collection is an Atom?!!

This flies in the face of the common understanding that a "collection" cannot be an "atom".
Nevertheless, in Lisp, arrays, vectors, hash tables, structures, class objects are all atoms.
The rationale (besides ancient history) is that the *implementation* ([`eval`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm)) does not have to look inside atoms - they evaluate to themselves (except for symbols).

### Quoting

`foo` is a
[`symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_symbol.htm),
`'foo` is [identical to `(quote foo)`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dc.htm), and `"foo"` is a string.

### Further Reading

You should take a look at a basic lisp textbook (e.g., ["Practical Common
Lisp"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) or ["ANSI Common Lisp"](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html)).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that there is a vector in Lisp.

Comment: Lisp has a rich and powerful library. Read up!